# Why i am getting this Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "s" LINE 1?

Tags: php, postgresql

why i am getting this error while running the following code.I am pasting a part of code here. the connection to the database established successfully.

**Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "s" LINE 1**

Comment: Why are the SQL Injection-sized holes always tagged with PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `pg_escape_string`

```
$product_name = pg_escape_string($product_name);
```